# Setting text alignment to justify in .md file works in VS Code but not in GitHub

Tags: github, markdown

I'm trying to set the text alignment of my README.md file to justify. I tried the following in VS Code and the preview showed exactly what I wanted.

```html
<p style="text-align: justify;">
My paragraph
</p>
```

But when I pushed it to GitHub, I saw that this line of code did not change alignment. I searched a little more and came up with this solution:

```html
<p align="justify"> 
My paragraph
</p>
```

And it worked on GitHub (and VS Code). My question is, what's the difference between GitHub and VS Code here? Why doesn't the first solution work for GitHub?

Answer (score 1):

I think first solution didn't work on GitHub is because GitHub's Markdown parser does not support using inline styles like style="text-align: justify;". Inline styles are often used in HTML to apply styling to a specific element, but in Markdown, it's better to use a more universal approach that is supported across all platforms.

'align' is a standard HTML attribute that is widely supported, including by GitHub's Markdown parser